# Display GoogleMaps in other fragment gives error , Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id'

Tags: android, google-maps

I create a new project with a Google Maps activity, generate the key and everything works fine. The problem is that I want to create the map in another fragment, so here is the code:
The `MapsActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.map, Fragment1.newInstance(), "Fragment1")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

The Fragment1 class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    mMap = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMap.getMapAsync(this);
    // Passing harcoded values for latitude & longitude. Please change as per your need. This is just used to drop a Marker on the Map
return  view;
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .title("Marker"));
}
```

And now is getting to me the error

`GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin`

Comment: Do you have your `google-services.json` in the project? What do your `strings.xml` look like?

Comment: Yes, I have the `.json`  and in the `strings.xml I have `<string name="google_app_id">xxxxxx</string> ` with my id